# GeoMesa export query error

Tags: cql, accumulo, geomesa

**Problem:**
When I try to run below query it gives error. Is there something missing in the CQL query or is a jar file missing ? Also whether it is just a GeoMesa error or accumulo error. Is there any other way to query GeoMesa and get results in a CSV file ?

Namespace: myNamespace
Collection: d1temp

**Query:**

```
geomesa export -u user -p password -c myNamespace.d1temp -f d1-json -q "WITHIN(geom, POLYGON((-6.4101 55.597244,-6.4101 50.947156,0.656067 50.947156,0.656067 55.597244,-6.4101 55.597244)))"
```

**Error:**

```
id,*geom:Point:srid=4326,short_text_field:String,long_text_field_1:String,long_text_field_2:String,security_tag:String,numerical_tag_1:Integer,numerical_tag_2:Double,timestamp:Date
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.ArrayList.sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V
    at org.locationtech.sfcurve.zorder.ZN.zranges(ZN.scala:212)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.curve.Z2SFC$.ranges(Z2SFC.scala:33)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.z2.Z2QueryableIndex$class.getQueryPlan(Z2QueryableIndex.scala:119)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.z2.Z2Index$.getQueryPlan(Z2Index.scala:20)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.z2.Z2Index$.getQueryPlan(Z2Index.scala:20)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$getQueryPlans$7$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:150)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$getQueryPlans$7$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:150)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.stats.MethodProfiling$class.profile(MethodProfiling.scala:20)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner.profile(QueryPlanner.scala:56)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$getQueryPlans$7.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:150)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$getQueryPlans$7.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:396)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.util.CloseableIterator$$anon$5.hasNext(CloseableIterator.scala:34)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.util.SelfClosingIterator$$anon$1.hasNext(CloseableIterator.scala:100)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.util.CloseableIterator$$anon$2.<init>(CloseableIterator.scala:66)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.util.CloseableIterator$class.ciFlatMap(CloseableIterator.scala:65)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.util.SelfClosingIterator$$anon$1.ciFlatMap(CloseableIterator.scala:98)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner.scan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:87)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner.executePlans(QueryPlanner.scala:108)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.QueryPlanner.runQuery(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReaderWithStats$$anonfun$2.apply(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:86)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReaderWithStats$$anonfun$2.apply(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:86)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.stats.MethodProfiling$class.profile(MethodProfiling.scala:26)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReaderWithStats.profile(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:77)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReaderWithStats.<init>(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:86)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReader$$anon$3.<init>(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:55)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureReader$.apply(AccumuloFeatureReader.scala:55)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStore.getFeatureReader(AccumuloDataStore.scala:439)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureCollection.reader(AccumuloFeatureSource.scala:171)
    at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.openIterator(DataFeatureCollection.java:230)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloFeatureCollection.openIterator(AccumuloFeatureSource.scala:134)
    at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.iterator(DataFeatureCollection.java:198)
    at org.geotools.data.store.DataFeatureCollection.features(DataFeatureCollection.java:187)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.DelimitedExport.write(FeatureExporter.scala:156)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.commands.ExportCommand.execute(ExportCommand.scala:52)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.common.Runner$class.main(Runner.scala:26)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.AccumuloRunner$.main(AccumuloRunner.scala:20)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.accumulo.AccumuloRunner.main(AccumuloRunner.scala)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs with Java 7.  GeoMesa requires Java 8.  The command 'java --version' will show you the details of the Java version you are using.

You'll need to check out how your OS handles multiple versions of Java, and update JAVA_HOME to point to a Java 8 installation.  After that, you'll be back on track!

Your CQL filters and the rest of the command looks great.  Personally I prefer 'bbox' or 'intersects' since I don't have to think about the argument order.  (If A intersects B, then B intersects A.  When A is within B, it doesn't imply that B is within A.)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I had Java 7 installed. Switching to Java 8 worked.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it!